# In a Linux signal handler, will x86 extended state always be in XSAVE format, or can it be in XSAVEC format as well?

Tags: linux, exception, signals, x86-64, avx

On x86-64, when a Linux user-mode program crashes, but there's a signal handler for that crash, does AVX extended state always get saved to the stack in `XSAVE` format, or can it be in `XSAVEC` ("compacted") format as well?

I'm wondering this so I can access the saved AVX context in my signal handler.

Specifically, `ucontext_t` member `fpregs` points to a structure containing the `FXSAVE` floating-point + SSE state.  `_libc_fpstate` contains a `_fpx_sw_bytes` overlaid at `&__glibc_reserved1[12]`.  This contains a magic value `FP_XSTATE_MAGIC1` marking that XSTATE (AVX, etc.) context is present.

However, to get to the portion of the context containing e.g. the high halves of the `ymm` registers, it seems like you have to use `CPUID` subfunction `0x0D` to get the offset for that particular XSTATE feature.  If the Linux kernel writes the user-mode signal frame using `XSAVEC` instead of `XSAVE`, it would mean that the algorithm to determine the offset is different.

Do I need to support both `XSAVE` and `XSAVEC` formats for finding the AVX context in a frozen context?